# Why SIZE_OF_STR returns 2 different answers for the same values?

Tags: c, sizeof, strlen

Why SIZE_OF_STR returns 7 and 5 values for "hello" string?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE_OF_STR(s) sizeof(s)/sizeof(char)-1
int main()
{
    char *x = "hello";
    printf("%d\n",SIZE_OF_STR(x));
    printf("%d",SIZE_OF_STR("hello"));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
7
5
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the 'sizeof' (a pointer pointing to an array)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeof-a-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first sizeof is actually doing sizeof of a pointer to char which is 8.

The second one is doing the sizeof of the constant string which yields 6 for "hello".

Your macro expression actually resolves the divison before the subtraction, therefore resulting in both 8-1=7 and 6-1=5.

Comment: [C operator precedence table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).  Division is listed at level 3, subtraction is at level 4.  Division wins!

Comment: Why this bug isn't visible in strlen?

Comment: @RomanP As explained [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/), what **strlen** returns is "the number of characters between the beginning of the string and the terminating null character (without including the terminating null character itself)", therefore it count characters instead of asking for the size of a variable, which is what **sizeof** does. If it solves your issue then please accept the answer ;D

Comment: it is a one of the most common duplicates

Comment: `sizeof` is a compile-time operator that tells you how much memory was allocated for something. `strlen()` is a runtime function that actually counts characters and stops at 0. They are completely unrelated.